# Not getting tokenized array from strtok_s()

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strtok

I am trying to get an array tokenized with the strtok_s() function, BUT I also want to include the delimiter where the array was tokenized. If it is a slash " /" I want the array to have slash wherever there was a token made using the slash "/" character.

I have written a function, that takes in the string and delimiter and returns another string with the tokens and delimiter.

However, it does not work as expected and I have no idea why. Also, I am not really good with the C language.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Below is my main cpp file and the console output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




struct token_stat {
    int n; // for total items in array
    char* r_array; // pointer to the array returned from function
};


//        function for passing a string and a delimeter and getting back
//        the array with tokenized items including the delimeter 
token_stat append_token_delim(char* string_in, char splitter[])
{
    token_stat result; 
    char* token = NULL ;      // initialize variables for STRTOK_S func
    char* next_token = NULL ;
    char* token_accum = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(string_in)) ;  // allcate memory twice that of the string we are tokenizing
    char* delim = splitter; // pointer to the delimeter in main function 
    int i = 0;


    token = strtok_s(string_in, delim, &next_token); // first call and getting the token
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        token_accum[i] = token[0]; // add the token to token_accum array
        token_accum[i + 1] = *delim;  // now add the delimeter character next to the 1st token
        printf("%s\t%s\n", token, delim); // print token and the delimeter
        token = strtok_s(NULL, delim, &next_token); // make call again to strtok to get next token
        i = i + 2;  // increment index by 2 to get to the next token
    }

    int numberOfTokens = sizeof(*token_accum) / sizeof(token_accum[0]);  // get total items in token_accum array for printing in main
    result.n = numberOfTokens;     // passing values to TOKEN_STAT STRUCT 
    result.r_array = token_accum;    // passing the array to STRUCT
    return result;    // returning the struct back 

}
// printing the array 
void print_tokens(token_stat in_array)
{  printf("Number of Tokens in Array; %d", in_array.n); 
}  


int main()
{
    char str[] = "- Thi;s,ansample()str;ing.";
    token_stat main_accum;
    char delimeter = '/';

    main_accum = append_token_delim(str, &delimeter);
    print_tokens(main_accum);





    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer returns the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to.

Comment: On surface, your token are strings, but you allocate array of chars (char *) to store all of them.you token array should be char **.

Comment: Also, the Mallon is wrong. Sizeof(...) will give you the size of the pointer, you probably want the length of the string (strlen)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how should I then allocate memory ?

Comment: _Below is my main cpp file_ It looks like C, uses C functions and C includes. To prevent confusions, I would give it suffix `.c` and compile with a C compiler. The only thing to adjust: `print_tokens(token_stat in_array)`. This works in C++ but not in C. It has to be `print_tokens(struct token_stat in_array)` in C. Similar in `append_token_delim()`.

Comment: Please do not use the C++ and C tags at the same time without a good reason.  They are different languages with very different programming techniques and idioms.

Comment: @L.F. got it. let me remove them

Comment: Use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to get the length of the null-terminated byte string?

Comment: Also remember that for any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`. For `i == 0` that means `p[0]` is `*p`. Think about that in the context of `token_accum[0]` and `*token_accum`, and what the result of that division might be.

Answer (score 0):

you want to store multiple strings in the token_accum but you are storing only the first character
`token_accum[i] = token[0];`

to store multiple strings you need an array of pointer
and you can store the strings like this

`token_accum[i] = token;`

Comment: isnt that the same ? token[0] is the same as token here because it is pointer

Comment: no token means a pointer . token[0] means the the first value pointed by token pointer